# how to implement ApolloGraphQl with Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, graphql, android-jetpack-compose

I have an app that has bottom Navigation bar which implemented with compose navigation. This bottom navigation bar navigate between different screen (each screen is a composable function).

I want to execute an enquiry using ApolloGraphQl Client inside home screen. However, if I want to execute the enquiry:

```
fun HomeScreen() {
    Text(text = "Home")
    val response = apolloClient.query(LaunchListQuery()).execute()
    Log.d("LaunchList", "Success ${response.data}")
    }
```

I get this error

```
Suspend function 'execute' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function
```

in ApollographQl [tutorial](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/tutorial/00-introduction), they used Fragments which has its own lifecycle, but I want to use composable functions and searching online didn't give me a clear answer.

I tried @oliverbj answer as:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val getLaunchOnClick: () -> Unit = {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            val response = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                apolloClient.query(LaunchListQuery()).execute()
            }
            Log.d("LaunchList", "Success ${response.await().data}")
        }
    }
    Text(text = "Home")
    Button(onClick = getLaunchOnClick) {
        Text("Launch")
    }
}
```